# is it possible to have editable markers with a leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet

I currently have around 10k markers stored in a kmz, I am trying to see if it is possible with leaflet to display these markers and allow them to be draggable / change colour etc by anyone who can access the page? most solution I have seen only update the markers in local storage so other users would not see the update? I have a geoserver and postgis as options for storing the markers. I just cant find any example of updating the marker and sending it back to the server?

Comment: In order to draw the marker, you have the Lat and Long. When you drag the marker, you chnge its Lat and Long. Just store them in an hidden field in your HTML page, and then these new coords will be send to the server when you'll submit the page, as if the Map was a form.

Comment: The answer to your global question is [yes](https://strcat.de/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html). If you're looking for specific information, please make more specific questions.